# Timezone and more problems with Cakephp 1.3 and PHP 5.3.2

Tags: cakephp, datetime, timezone, php

on server i have php 5.3.2, and cakephp 1.3.

when i run cakephp application, it gives me following errors:

> Warning (2): strtotime() [http://php.net/function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead [ROOT/cakephp/cake/libs/cache.php, line 570]

Also, I'm getting some more errros:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /htdocs/cakephp/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248 Fatal error: Call to a member function cd() on a non-object in /htdocs/cakephp/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248

Timezone in php.ini is defined as Europe/London

I'm always getting that error, despite I define or not [`date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set), or Europe/London, or whatever...

really frustrating......... please help...

UPDATE: something is wrong with my installation of php... if i run

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

... it gives me blank screen. no result...

is there maybe a problem?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the timezone in your code? Perhaps in your app_controller's beforeFilter() ?

Comment: looks like i have some problem with installation of php... please, take a look at updated part of my question.

Comment: ***Note:*** The `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Answer (score 26):

To handle the first warning you need to uncomment the line `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` in /app/config/core.php. You can replace `UTC` with your timezone as Leo suggested.

Comment: unfortunately, i did that before i post this question... also i tried several different timezones, and get same error every time. also, please check UPDATED part of my question... for some reason, i can not execute simple php function date. i think that there may be a problem, something i did not enabled, or installed, or...?

Comment: Change your file to `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); echo date("Y"); ?>`.

Comment: i did set error_reporting(E_ALL), and errors i'm getting are: 

Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /htdocs/index.php on line 9 Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /htdocs/index.php on line 9

Comment: That is php bug http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48882. Try to add TZ=GMT in (apache) init.d script. If that does not help ask the question on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 8):

As Leo Said, is an issue with PHP 5.3. The best solution is to modify your web server php.ini and set

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"
```

Or if you can't modify web server php.ini you can add this options to root .htaccess file on your site:

```
php_flag date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and Googling led me to this post.

I fixed the problem by adding the line `date_default_timezone_set("America/Anchorage");` to the top of *[cake base directory]/libs/cache.php*

You probably want to replace *America/Anchorage* with your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error for a while since the hosting co. upgraded to 5.3 too

In the /app/config/config.php, around line 244, there's a note about un-commenting the next line when running on 5.3

I just changed the next line to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto'); // your favourite time-zone here - and don't get me started about why Toronto is U.S. city (joking)
```

You could put that line in bootstrap.php, but you might get this error still, config.php is loaded first

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using cakeshell to run command line cron scripts. After much hassle I figured out that in addition to bancer's solution above I needed import core.php into my php shell scripts as such:

```
function main() {
    App::import('Controller', 'Core');

    //run controllers and actions that cause error here

}
```

Adding 
'Core' to App::import() solved it for me.