# Warning (2): strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: cakephp

```
Warning (2): strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no DST' instead [CORE\cake\libs\cache.php, line 570]
Code | Context

$settings = array(
 "engine" => "File",
 "path" => "C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\tmp\cache\persistent\",
 "prefix" => "cake_core_",
 "lock" => false,
 "serialize" => true,
 "isWindows" => true,
 "duration" => "+10 seconds",
 "probability" => 100
)

strtotime - [internal], line ??
CacheEngine::init() - CORE\cake\libs\cache.php, line 570
FileEngine::init() - CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 81
Cache::_buildEngine() - CORE\cake\libs\cache.php, line 151
Cache::config() - CORE\cake\libs\cache.php, line 126
Configure::__loadBootstrap() - CORE\cake\libs\configure.php, line 421
Configure::getInstance() - CORE\cake\libs\configure.php, line 52
include - CORE\cake\bootstrap.php, line 38
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 76


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\cake\libs\cache\file.php on line 248

Fatal error: Call to a member function cd() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\cake\libs\cache\file.php on line 248
```

Comment: …yes? Would you care to formulate a question as well?

Comment: Blessed as I am with the ability to derive questions from otherwise useless dumps of error messages, I can see why mere mortals might have troubles with this :-) Perhaps, given that SO is a Q&A site, you should ask a question.

Answer (score 44):

/app/config/core.php:

```
/**
 * If you are on PHP 5.3 uncomment this line and correct your server timezone
 * to fix the date & time related errors.
 */
    //date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: I used it. Now I am getting the error: Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/authbridge/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php on line 177

Comment: additional, under Cakephp 2.x, you must uncomment and edit `//Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');` line.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this was the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely well documented here and elsewhere.
[Timezone and more problems with Cakephp 1.3 and PHP 5.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370403/cakephp-timezone-and-more-problems-with-cakephp-1-3-and-php-5-3-2)

Part of becoming a proficient developer is making some effort at problem solving yourself. That's how you learn. When there is so much coverage of this problem, you're unlikely to find a sympathetic ear here because everybody knows you've not made any effort yourself.

Comment: This is a little conceited mate, the OP is here to get help.

Answer (score 1):

The very warning mentions the function in question, did you search for that? [Here's what it says in the docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the time zone is not valid, and/or a E_STRICT or E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable. See also date_default_timezone_set()

In other words, you should explicitly set the TZ for your server, [either in php.ini](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), or using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

To remove this E_STRICT or E_WARNING message please uncomment the line with `date_default_timezone_set` in `app/config/core.php`