# How to fix PHP errors related to timezone (function.strtotime and function.date)

Tags: php

Upgrading to a new server, I two repeated errors:

> Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead in...

and

> Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead in

How do I go about fixing these?

Code in question is this:

```
'date' => date("Y-M-d",strtotime($Array['_dateCreated'])),
```

I've tried putting this in an include at the top of all my pages:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4428546/819417

Comment: ***Note:*** The `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`date.timezone` in `php.ini` can fix this globally.

Comment: For some reason my /etc/php.ini file's additions like date.timezone seem to be ignored even after restarting apache.

Comment: Turns out that the /etc/php.ini isn't the right one, rather the [domain]/httpdocs/etc/php.ini is the one that has an effect.

Comment: You can find out which `php.ini` your server cares about by doing `phpinfo()` and looking for `Loaded Configuration File`.

Answer (score 28):

Fixed this by putting

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

In the actual file that was complaining.

Comment: i prefer this . because i don't want to update my php.ini file. Also, you can set default timezone to your project globally