# phpDocumentor, not working, PHP Warning: strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone

Tags: php-5.3, pear, strftime, phpdoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix PHP errors related to timezone (function.strtotime and function.date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811603/how-to-fix-php-errors-related-to-timezone-function-strtotime-and-function-date)

I installed PhpDocumentor-1.4.0a2.tgz which is the latest version on CentOS 5.7 64, my current lamp installation is with php 5.3.3

I am using

> pear install phpDocumentor-alpha

after installing it the following is shown:

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. 
>   You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the 
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting 
>   this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' 
>   instead in PEAR/Validate.php on line 454 and 486

I know this error has to do with the version of php, and 5.3 is not compatible with PEAR.
I did not mind because the instalation process gave me an ok.

The I tried to generate the documentation, it is not being completed for some reason.

```
$ phpdoc -c /usr/share/pear/data/PhpDocumentor/user/bigstep.ini
```

> PHP Warning:  strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. 
>   You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. 
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, 
>   you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' 
>   instead in /usr/share/pear/PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/Smarty-2.6.0/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 370

It is a php warning that should not be  stoping the documentation generation. But, the process gets in the middle,
and at the end does not generate the files.

it seems that I have to check on those libraries myself. Does anyone have seen this error before, what should I try next to resolve this issue

Comment: You should probably **read the error message** it has nothing to do with pear being incompatible with php 5.3 (which isn't true) and everything to do with using date functions without setting the _required_ `date.timezone` setting.

Comment: Not working is not a good way to word your questions title. What you see is a configuration issue, I'll try to find an existing questions that elaborates more in this. And as @AD7six wrote, PEAR is compatible with PHP 5.3, at least a recent version is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix PHP errors related to timezone (function.strtotime and function.date)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811603/how-to-fix-php-errors-related-to-timezone-function-strtotime-and-function-date), [PHP Configuration: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213608/php-configuration-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Set the timezone in your php.ini

Comment: This answer would benefit from more detail if you have time.

Comment: The details are in the question. :)

_Is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier._

So, because is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings, you should set the date.timezone entry in you php.ini if you want to get rid of this warning.